# Using Statsplot and Groupedbar in Julia for Multiple Plots

Tags: julia

I want to plot electricity generation from 2015-2021 for month of January till April. I use StatsPlots

```
using CSV, DataFrames, StatsPlots, Measures, Plots
gr()

df1 = CSV.read("/home/browni/LasthrimProjection/csv/energy-charts_Public_net_electricity_generation_in_Germany_in_January_Excel.csv", DataFrame)
df2 = CSV.read("/home/browni/LasthrimProjection/csv/energy-charts_Public_net_electricity_generation_in_Germany_in_February_Excel.csv", DataFrame)
df3 = CSV.read("/home/browni/LasthrimProjection/csv/energy-charts_Public_net_electricity_generation_in_Germany_in_March_Excel.csv", DataFrame)
df4 = CSV.read("/home/browni/LasthrimProjection/csv/energy-charts_Public_net_electricity_generation_in_Germany_in_April_Excel.csv", DataFrame)

df1.Month = join.(split.(rpad.(string.(df1.Month),4,"0"),'.'), '-')
df2.Month = join.(split.(rpad.(string.(df2.Month),4,"0"),'.'), '-')
df3.Month = join.(split.(rpad.(string.(df3.Month),4,"0"),'.'), '-')
df4.Month = join.(split.(rpad.(string.(df4.Month),4,"0"),'.'), '-')

a1 = groupedbar(df1.Month, Matrix(df1[:,2:end]), title="January", xlabel="Year", ylabel="Energy(GWh)", 
    titlefontsize=14, bar_position=:stack, bar_width=0.6, label="")
a2 = groupedbar(df2.Month, Matrix(df2[:,2:end]), title="February", xlabel="Year", ylabel="Energy(GWh)", 
    titlefontsize=14, bar_position=:stack, bar_width=0.6, label="")
a3 = groupedbar(df3.Month, Matrix(df3[:,2:end]), title="March", xlabel="Year", ylabel="Energy(GWh)", 
    titlefontsize=14, bar_position=:stack, bar_width=0.6, label="")
a4 = groupedbar(df3.Month, Matrix(df3[:,2:end]), title="April", xlabel="Year", ylabel="Energy(GWh)", 
    titlefontsize=14, bar_position=:stack, bar_width=0.6, , 
    label=permutedims(names(df4)[2:end]))

#plot(title = "Electricity Generation in Germany", xticks=false,yticks=false)

plot(a1, a2, a3, a4, layout = @layout([grid(2,2)]))

# Adjusting the font size, layout, colors
# xlabel and ylabel can be put below for uniform labeling
plot!(tickfontsize=4, framestyle = :box, guidefontsize=4,
    legendfontsize=4, legend=:outertop)
```

1. The problem is I want the legend to be below and plotted nicely, if possible in circle layout, how? each plot (a1 to a4 has the same label)

You can obtain the csv here:
https://energy-charts.info/charts/energy/chart.htm?l=en&c=DE&chartColumnSorting=default&interval=month&year=-1

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to change the argument in plot!() to:

```
plot!(..,legend =:bottom)
```

does this give the desired outcome?